# Is there any default or recommended style for macros?

Tags: c, coding-style, macros

I've found a couple of different styled macros.
For header files something like this:

```
#define __HEADER_H__
#define _HEADER_H_
#define _header_h
```

simple macros:

```
#define SOMEMACRO something
#define somemacro something
#define SOME_MACRO something
```

macros with arguments:

```
#define func_macro() something() // arguments not used?
#define FUNC_MACRO something()
#define func_macro something()
```

---

So my question is: Are some of them good or bad styled? Is there a "default" style for macro names?

Comment: My coding style: Don't use them.

Comment: Definitely **don't** use `__` or `_H`. Both are reserved for the implementation. More generally, identifiers starting with two underscores, or an underscore, followed by a capital letter.

Comment: capitalizing is usually a good idea, escpecially if you want to warn the developer that it does something unusual.

Comment: Exactly, capitalizing all of your macros is a very good idea. That's about it for macro naming conventions. The only issue, then, is your first example. Common ones are `HEADER_H`, `HEADER_H_`, and `HEADER_H_INCLUDED`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII if you don't use macros, what do you do with magic numbers?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII and how do you portably implement header guards without macros?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII you'll eventually need macros -- they're not there because K&R didn't have anything to do and were having fun by saying "I'm borer, let's create a C preprocessor", but they saw the potential of it and the need for it. If you think macros are evil, I have to deduce that you can't properly use macros, only abuse them...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII try implementing, for example,  the Standard C function `assert` without them. Knowing when and how to use macros properly is an important part of your programming arsenal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Indian Hill C style guide, as amended at UofT, UW, and elsewhere](http://www.maultech.com/chrislott/resources/cstyle/indhill-cstyle.pdf):

**11. Naming Conventions** (page 13):

> #define constants should be in all CAPS.

...

> Many macro ``functions'' are in all CAPS. Some macros (such as getchar and putchar ) are in lower case since they may also exist as functions. Lower-case macro names are only acceptable if the macros behave like a function call, that is, they evaluate their parameters exactly once and do not assign values to named parameters. Sometimes it is impossible to write a macro that behaves like a function even though the arguments are evaluated exactly once.

Also read chapters 12 (Constants) and 13 (Macros), on page 14 of the pdf document.

---

Their naming conventions are IMHO very reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Using all capital letters is definitely the way to go for constants. However, I would suggest never using function macros. I recommend writing in-line functions. Function macros used in certain situations can result in logical errors. For example:

```
#define FUNC(x) x + x

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    b = FUNC(a++);
}
```

The result is undefined and will most likely not be the intended one.

Comment: You can't even count on the three.  This one is Undefined Behavior.